# How come the Bernstein operator creates a polynomial of the same degree as its input function?

Tags: computational-geometry

I read that the Bernstein operator

$$
\mathfrak{B}_f(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right) \; B^n_i(t)
$$

applied to a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $m \leq n$ with the Bernstein polynomial

$$
B^n_i(t) = \binom{n}{i} \; t^i \; (1-t)^{n-i}
$$

returns a new polynomial also of degree $m$. In other words, the Bernstein operator does not increase its degree when applied to $f$.

How is this possible? Since we're only sampling $f$ at a certain interval, wouldn't the original degree of $f$ become irrelevant? How can the degree of the result be smaller than $n$, since we will have at least one $t^n$ in the expression resulting from one of the Bernstein polynomials?

Comment: Questions like these might be better suited for the math site (math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I wasn't sure where to post this. I decided to put it here since I learned about Bernstein polynomials in a computational-geometry class in my CompSci studies. I'll take a look at math exchange for further questions :)

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients of $t^k$ for $k \gt m$ can cancel out.

For instance, let $f(x) = x^m$ and consider the coefficient of $t^n$ for $n \gt m$.

The coefficient we get is

$$n^{-m}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} i^m (-1)^{n-i}$$

which can be shown to be zero by starting with

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} x^{i} (-1)^{n-i} = (x-1)^{n}$$

And differentiating and multiplying by $x$, $m$ times, and then setting $x=1$.

For $m \lt n$, this indeed comes out to be zero.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer has confused me a bit more. Did you factorize $(1-t)^{n-i}$ from the Bernstein polynomial for each term in the sum to get to that coefficient? Also, wouldn't the result need to be non-zero for every $m<n$?

Comment: Note that $n$ and $m$ are fixed above. I am only showing you that the coefficient of $t^n$ can be zero. I am not considering other powers $t^k$, for $k \lt n$. I took the coefficient of $t^n$ from $t^{i}(1-t)^{n-i}$, which comes to $(-1)^{n-i}$ and multiplied with the other terms and added them up, and showed that it is zero if $n \gt m$. Is it clearer now?